Date validator fails using Express-validator on OSX but not Linux
I'm having inconsistent behavior from express-validator v7 ("express-validator": "^7.0.1",).  I'm sending the following payload
{"startDate":"2024-04-25"}

to my server with the following validator
import { checkSchema } from 'express-validator'
const schema = checkSchema({
  startDate: {
    errorMessage: 'startDate must be a date YYYY-MM-DD',
    isDate: {
      options: {
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        delimiters: ['-'],
      },
    },
    toDate: true,
    isAfter: {
      errorMessage: 'The start date must be after today',
      options: {
        comparisonDate: new Date().toISOString(),
      },
    },
  },
})

which does not seem to have an issue when it's running on Linux but tosses an error every time I'm testing on OSX/macos.
{
  "error": {
    "code": "validation_failed",
    "httpStatusCode": 400,
    "messages": [
      "startDate must be a date YYYY-MM-DD"
    ],
    "msg": "Validation failed"
  }
}

I've had success with .ISO8601() elsewhere but we only need accuracy to the day level for this endpoint. Is there something I'm missing or could do to make sure I have consistent behavior across platforms? Perhaps I have to write my own custom validator because dates are handled differently on different platforms?
